# ASP.NET Core, Entity Framework - Word document

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ms-word

I've got a project using ASP.NET Core I'm using multi page web application (template found here https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates). It's all working fine which ask user to enter info and save to database.

My question is how do I get these details entered to save/download as a Word document or PDF on my local machine? Is there a way to do this? I've seen people talking about DocX, Telerik and stuff but not sure how I can use them in my project which is structured in solution explorer as Dto files, entity class, JS files, controllers, models and views all works fine just need to save it as Word document after all details are entered when ever the code runs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save your database data in a word/pdf document, you have to create this document in your server and download it. You can use the official supported library [Open-XML-SDK (Github)](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK) from Microsoft to create the document. Here is a tutorial to start: [Create a word document with OpenXml and C#](http://www.ludovicperrichon.com/create-a-word-document-with-openxml-and-c/) by Ludovic Perrichon